# GROUP-BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i have this query:

```
SELECT
SolutionName    -- Solution_NAM
from  Table_View
Group By 1
```

where Table_View is of course a view.
I am gettign this error message:

Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Can you help me resolve this?
It´s inside Ms SQL Server 2008

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can't group by column ordinal in SQL Server. You need to specify the name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you cannot give Group by 1

try

```
SELECT
SolutionName    -- Solution_NAM
from  Table_View
Group By SolutionName
```

Answer (score 1):

Martin's statement about GROUP BY is correct, although you >can< definitely use a column ordinal instead of a column name in an ORDER BY, in various versions of SQL (I'm thinking TSQL, which is ISO standard in most core SQL syntax).

But it's wise practice not to use column ordinals in ORDER BY statements, even though they do work. Why? If the query is a part of a stored proc, and the table schema is altered by adding a column to the original table (or view), there is no guarantee that the original column ordering will be maintained by the change. Which would mean that you could be ordering by an unintended and meaningless column, which then breaks your application.

It's far better practice to use column names rather than ordinals every time (although like count(*), don't get hung up on it if it's ad-hoc querying for your own use that will never see the light of day in production).

Comment: Queries that use _Ordinals_ can really complicate long term maintenance, also it is very easy for devs and DBAs alike to start with a reference query and change it without noticing that the Ordinal statements may not have the same meaning. Using explicit column names or expressions reduces these sort of issues. You also cannot us an Ordinal if your expression doesn't exist in the result set ;)