# Display value in column although it is excluded by a WHERE condition over another column

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=341dbcb5ac0b4d169438a5724ef0816e)**

```
CREATE TABLE operations (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    orderID VARCHAR(255),
    itemID VARCHAR(255),
    event_date DATE,
    order_volume INT,
    shipped_volume INT
);

INSERT INTO operations
(itemID, orderID, event_date, order_volume, shipped_volume
)
VALUES 
("Item_01", "Order_XYZ", "2020-05-01", "600", "0"),
("Item_01", "Order_XYZ", "2020-05-18", "0", "315"),
("Item_01", "Order_XYZ", "2020-05-19", "0", "100"),
("Item_01", "Order_MTE", "2020-08-15", "400", "0"),
("Item_01", "Order_OBD", "2020-08-21", "500", "0"),
("Item_01", "Order_OBD", "2020-11-17", "0", "380"),

("Item_02", "Order_TLP", "2020-02-02", "500", "0"),
("Item_02", "Order_TLP", "2020-02-10", "0", "175"),
("Item_02", "Order_ADF", "2020-03-27", "100", "0"),

("Item_03", "Order_BBI", "2020-03-12", "700", "0"),

("Item_04", "Order_DXR", "2020-12-09", "260", "0"),
("Item_04", "Order_DXR", "2020-12-15", "0", "110"),
("Item_04", "Order_DXR", "2020-12-15", "0", "60"),
("Item_04", "Order_FGU", "2020-12-15", "0", "80");
```

**Expected Result:**

```
    itemID    |    orderID    |      sum(order_volume)   |      sum(shipped_volume)  
--------------|---------------|--------------------------|---------------------------------------
    Item_04   |   Order_DXR   |            260           |             250
    Item_02   |   Order_TLP   |            500           |             175
    Item_01   |   Order_XYZ   |            600           |             415
    Item_01   |   Order_OBD   |            500           |             380
```

---

In the result above I want to list all `itemID` and `orderID` that have `shipped_volume > 0`. 
Therefore, I went with this query:

```
SELECT 
itemID,
orderID,
sum(order_volume),
sum(shipped_volume)
FROM operations
WHERE shipped_volume > 0
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

It gives me almost the result I am looking for. 
The only issue I have is that it puts a `0` for all rows in column `sum(order_volume)` which is caused by the `WHERE` condition.

What do I need to change so it also displays the `sum(order_volume)` of all `items` and `orders` that have a `shipped_volume > 0`?

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for... "sum(order_volume) of all items and orders that have a shipped_volume > 0" all rows with shipped volume > 0 have an order volume = 0. The sum will always be 0. What should be the result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be what you are looking for if i understand correctly :

```
SELECT 
  itemID,
  orderID,
  sum(order_volume),
  sum(shipped_volume)
FROM operations
GROUP BY 1,2
HAVING sum(shipped_volume) > 0;
```

[**FIND A DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=dd20deba351aa254b2c4b27a50d7f650)

Answer (score 1):

Simply us `HAVING` instead of where, this example is the perfect exmaple of how to use `HAVING`, think of it as applying the filter *AFTER* calculating the group results!

```
SELECT 
  itemID,
  orderID,
  SUM(order_volume),
  SUM(shipped_volume)
FROM operations
GROUP BY itemID, orderID
HAVING SUM(shipped_volume) > 0;
```

[Your fiddle updated](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=b3f87fb7eb0b12a840d823b31f43c98c)

More reading on `HAVING` specifically for MySQL:
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx

**NOTE:** In this example I have used explicit column name references instead of ordinals, there are many supporting arguments for this, I go with "it is more expressive and harder to get wrong".

- Ordinals in `GROUP BY` is not supported in all db engines or versions.
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/45569726/1690217

Answer (score -1):

You have to use group by subquery:

```
SELECT 
itemID,
orderID,
(select sum(order_volume) from operations o where o.orderid = op.orderid) as order_volumne ,
sum(shipped_volume)
FROM operations op
WHERE shipped_volume > 0
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Comment: While this will produce the expected results, it is not necessary to use sub-queries to achieve this type of output, see the answers using the `HAVING` clause which was designed specifically for this.

Comment: This will give exactly the same result and it depends on volume of data to use which option but this is also one of the options.

Comment: The execution plan of a inlined sub query like this means that as the number of rows increases the performance will only get worse, not better. The RDBMS has specific optimisations for `HAVING` so we should use them when it makes sense to do so.